# Effects of no-clean flux or RMA flux residue on signals

Tags: analog, soldering, assembly, flux

I keep on hearing that no-clean solder paste or flux  is bad for analog or digital signals because it makes analog signals "noisy" and promotes cross talk on digital signals.

Like this claim:

> Flux residues can add noise on analog-to-digital conversion circuits.

Source: [Mike Jones - Expert Comment](http://www.circuitnet.com/experts/73284.html)

or this:

> 'No-clean' fluxes have been found to be electrically conductive and
> are not easy to clean (requiring strong solvents and scrubbing).

Source: answer to ["Why do we need to remove flux from circuit boards?" - Spehro Pefhany](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/170941/why-do-we-need-to-remove-flux-from-circuit-boards)

I realize that it's probably not good to have anything on the surface of the PCB between traces. I realize that corrosion is bad. But if no-clean residue or RMA flux residue is left on a board, what happens? Most people say, it's bad don't do it.

My question is, through what mechanism does leaving a residue on a PCB affect performance? How does it affect performance Is it a parasitic resistance? Parasitic capacitance?

I could see a promoted parasitic capacitance with a residue and leakage current. How much?

Is there some other mechanism besides promoting cross talk that I'd have to worry about?

Has anyone ran into this problem directly?

**Edit:**

What is the mechanism for this noise? Can it be traced to some physical process?

Comment: Addressing corrosion, not its electrical properties...Have seen crystalline honey-coloured rosin flux extending onto Cu trace where the Cu underneath is bright, while adjacent Cu trace exposed to environment is oxidized (dull brown). Impressed with flux *protecting* rather than *corroding* - seems its room-temperature activity is very low.

Comment: I once left water soluble flux on a board, the board failed and had poor conductivity on some through hole parts pins. I believe this was due to corrosion, the board worked fine for half a year and then broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have run into this problem with precision photodetection circuitry. After reworking a board any leftover flux threw off the instrument calibration due to increased surface leakage bypassing guard features on the PCB. This was on the order of 500pA to a few nA depending on how thick the flux layer was. Cleaning the amplifiers very carefully with IPA and a small amount of acetone as a drying agent fixed 'er right up. Generally I do not worry about no-clean flux residues outside of precision amplifiers, potentially out of my own ignorance. I have yet to attribute an observed problem with no-clean flux in non-precision or non-critical circuits. Case by case like most things I suppose.