# How long can you leave flux on a PCB?

Tags: pcb, flux

How long can flux be left on a PCB?

I am working on one of my PCBs and I have put flux on it to solder. Can I leave it overnight. Is that ok? Or how long can flux be on the board?

**update:** 715 water solderble. My question is can any type of flux live it over night?

Comment: What do the instructions for the flux say?

Comment: Practically speaking, a flux intended for **electronic** (vs plumbing/mechanical/jewelry) usage is probably mild enough that you can leave it overnight (if not substantially longer), at least on a *prototype* where you goal is to validate a design, not build a long-life *product*.  Additionally, there fluxes which are designated no-clean, in that they are intended to be left on the circuit permanently.

Comment: Flux labeled "no-clean" does *not* imply that you never have to clean it off... see: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159492/chipquick-smd291-no-clean-paste-flux-conductive

Answer (score 2):

Water-soluble Flux such as Kester AZ2331 **MUST** be removed from the PCB as quickly as possible after soldering.

The manufacturer of your Flux will have their recommendations in the data sheet.

Our experience is that Kester Water-soluble flux left on the PCB for more than several hours results in the beginning of corrosion.