# I would like to know what type of op-amp this circuit is

Tags: circuit-design, differential, differential-amplifier, single-supply-op-amp, non-inverting

This circuit is connected to 250V AC power and I would like to calculate the values ​​of the resistor and capacitor, but I don't know which formula to use to calculate it.

[image]

I think this circuit is similar to the differential (subtractive) amplifier, but I don't know what values ​​to replace V1 and V2 with.

[image]

I thought about using cyclic calculations. Non-inverting op-amp because I think that the LINE wire is the wire that has electricity and the NEUTRAL wire is the wire that does not have electricity. Therefore, when electricity flows from the LINE wire into the positive pin of the LM324N, it will be a non-inverting op-amp circuit.

[image]

Please advise me which formula should I use to calculate and what should I substitute the inlet pressure for.

Comment: Your first proposal looks correct. I don't understand "but I don't know what values ​​to replace V1 and V2 with"; can you elaborate?

Comment: From where you copied this circuit? It looks familiar but your image has no component values, they might be in the BOM file that relates to the schematics.

Answer (score 3):

Begin with why several resistors are used in series: -

[image]

Mains AC voltage may be up to 270 volts RMS (typically 240 volts RMS in the UK) so you need to ensure that any resistor in the input chain has sufficient voltage rating to avoid it being exceeded by the mains AC.

The circuit itself is a differential amplifier with DC offset control via IC3C so, it's equivalent to your 2nd circuit. Use its formula.

> *I think that the LINE wire is the wire that has electricity and the
> NEUTRAL wire is the wire that does not have electricity*

You can't rely on that; they may become reversed so, a differential amplifier is used that overcomes any line/neutral reversal.

To calculate values you need to know how big the AC input voltage might be and, what  AC voltage you want to appear on V_SENSE. That defines the gain of your circuit but, one thing is for sure, the gain will be significantly less than one AND, the series resistor chain might be several hundred kΩ in value.

You will also make R18 and R19 the same value (possibly a few kΩ each AND, to keep the differential amplifier working as best as it can, you will need to make C4 and C5 the same value (possibly around 10 nF or less).

> *but I don't know what values ​​to replace V1 and V2 with*

You can assume that one is 0 volts and the other is the full AC voltage for the purposes of calculation; the use of a differential amplifier means that you can make this simplifying assumption.

One bit of advice; simulate your circuit and try things out before committing to a PCB.

Comment: not really DC offset control, there is no pot. most likely R21 and 22 are equal and it is just a rail splitter so the circuit can run off a 9V battery. The circuit appears to be looking at the imbalance of the L and N, with a bit of low pass filtering on the output. Most likely the accuracy requirements are low enough that the 4.5V or so of error doesn't matter too much. Probably this circuit is used to trigger some kind of warning or cutout if the mains imbalance gets too much.

Comment: I chose to use the phrase DC offset control because it both sets the DC offset (2.5 volts not 4.5 volts) and guarantees a low impedance at node OFFSET_V. This means that you can adjust R21 and R22 and not worry about the impedance changing at OFFSET_V. I stand by the term DC offset control. The circuit is NOT looking at the imbalance of L and N but looking at the difference between L and N. That is what a differential amplifier does and, it does so without being too affected by the imbalance of L and N. What this circuit likely does is calculate power but that is speculation @danmcb

Comment: you are correct, not the imbalance, but indeed the differential between L and N. The other stage is a rail splitter, however. I was looking on my phone, the 5 looked like a 9, so yes 2.5V but that is what it is. It is a very standard way of running an op amp off a single supply.

Comment: I have a question. I wonder if R21 and R22 need to be equal? And why do they have to be the same?

Comment: @Noting they don't need to be equal; they are currently making a mid-rail voltage at about 2.5 volts but, that mid-rail voltage should be nominally in the middle range of the ADC in the Nano. If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Andy aka
Do you have a method for choosing or a method for calculating R21 and R22 values? Can you advise me?

Comment: @Noting There's nothing particularly problematic with any value between 1 kohm and 100 kohm.

Answer (score 2):

Let’s look at the voltage sensor. What’s shown is a differential amplifier that has a 2.5V offset on the (+) side. This provides an output swing at IC3A that is centered on 2.5V.

Why differential, if neutral is supposedly 0V? Well, it isn't. First, line and neutral can be swapped, so we need to cover both cases. Also, swapped or not, neutral isn’t exactly 0V either: there is wiring IR drop to consider, which can build up to several volts on neutral. We need to account for that too in order to get an accurate voltage measurement. So differential it is.

That out of the way, we need to figure the diff amp gain. Short answer: we need to scale the gain to both what the Arduino needs and what the LM324 can handle without clipping.

The diff amp equation you show is correct, except that it doesn't account for the offset voltage added. Fortunately, the math works out easily since we have equal values (Rf) for both the feedback and (+) reference. The equation is then just (v1 - v2) x Rf/Ri **+ Vref**. Thus, with (+) input referenced to 2.5V instead of GND, with 0V differential input we get 2.5V (V_Offset) as the baseline value. Easy, huh?

More about differential op-amp calculations here: https://www.electronicshub.org/differential-amplifier/

What does the Arduino need? Let’s assume that the Arduino can accept an analog signal of 0 to 5V (Arduino default is for analog in to be between 0 to its Vdd value, in this case 5V.)

But we also need to avoid the LM324 swinging too close its rails because it will clip, and we also to leave a bit of overdrive margin.

So to be safe let’s limit the LM324 swing to between 0.5 and 4.5V, a +/-2V swing for the 250Vrms input. This gives a bit of headroom in case our line goes Nigel Tufnel and goes a bit over 250Vrms.

Now also consider that your ‘250V’ signal is an RMS voltage, which will actually have a voltage swing of about +/-353.6V. From this we infer that the IC3A gain needs to be 2/353.6 to give the +/-2V swing. Let's make it nice round numbers as 2/354.

We now have a rough idea of the op-amp's input to feedback ratio needs to be: 2 to 354. So we can choose **2k for Rf feedback** (R18/R19) and **354k total for Ri input** (those six resistors in series), or **59.0k** for each.

Speaking of which, why *is* there a bunch of resistors in series on the input? Resistors have a *voltage rating* that is dependent on their physical size. Depending on type, to obtain a high enough rating several resistors are connected in series. SMT resistors in particular have very low voltage ratings: just 40 to 50V for an EIA 0402 size for example.

So six 0402's in series are out, as this only gets us to 300V. With six 0603's each rated at 75V we get 450V overall, which is enough.

More about resistor voltage ratings here: [Do surface mount resistors have voltage ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244279/do-surface-mount-resistors-have-voltage-ratings)

Now as far as the capacitors, probably they’re all 0.1uF. C5 and C9 might be smaller values than that, but based on the bandwidth needed 0.1uF should be ok.

Note that R20 and C9 form a second low-pass filter after the op-amp. Again, 2k would be a reasonable value for R20.

On the current sensor the [Allegro ACS712 datasheet](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf) recommends 1nf on the FILTER pin (on your diagram it's C2.)

Quick and dirty, here's a mock-up of the voltage circuit using the above assumptions ([simulate it here](https://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEA2AzNA7ATi8gHACxhaKTJYgKSUgGqUCmAtGGAFABOlATHiKgm48%20BOFHDxInYbTGCRyAuLCS2AcxkFFmvNT1sASjIFD5-bnvGialmAjYB3WqiGjqZt1EfOhqfD-5IJSknOl8g-j9A4O9UKNQIuOR%20Qi8uJPBeEG5rMCzqCzhYqLy%20DIs%20EOzcrLBkalK0yOSEpRzqVvFCqS5dTL46hvz%20BDcekD7uHPB67OmO0fhvdrm2606qwdXqgvm2ADcUNsg%20bTACYPBKBfQEBDiSBCwXDFRK8TtvPsaz-O9f05Kc4xJzaCpHbZVMHTSZ7JwrRoIrBCcZhfrNdEFJYAY2yCGSfRc1D6DWYGCg0AQGHIxEKrxceG0MDg7HhNT4KxJy2sk3xE30TiJ-IxXMFUUJJT%20uLRtICjVJTHJLGg3CwGEEkFQarQYDwCDw9GZkHYGhlyIC4IFcqyCDymLYfj4tqEjVGQOGUgAhjtsicMeCBkgWEgVJIGtA1URzrasE9uPqsAMIxgiLwCFgwKMqRg8C6w2xvWi3koMsWJuAg5mJGHstB0zh1fAcjhI7WQ-mAPb8CBM2SJkBYWAuW0YY2oFOEMCG2Asrrd-hsIA)):

[image]

How are the signals used?

You'll notice that the Arduino has three inputs: V_Sense, I_Sense, and V_Offset. The Arduino senses V_Offset and subtracts it from V_Sense to calculate the voltage, which as we know swings positive and negative. That subtract operation also cancels out inaccuracy in the midpoint reference, including variations in 5V.

I_Sense will also be an offset bipolar signal that's referenced to 5V/2. Again, V_Offset can also be used to subtract from I_Offset to obtain the bipolar current value.

As far as the algorithms to compute the various parameters (RMS current, RMS voltage, RMS power, power factor, etc.) there are many Arduino references to choose from. Short take: some lightweight DSP is involved, with some tricks used to avoid slow operations like divides or square roots.

Comment: I have a question about calculating Rf and Ri values.
Can I just use V = 250 V? (Don't take 250 times root2)
And I don't understand where 2.5V (V_Offset) comes from.

Comment: You mean, make the gain 2/250 instead of 2/354? No. The op-amp swing will be too large because you are amplifying the whole peak-to-peak waveform, not its RMS value.

Comment: I don't understand where 2.5V (V_Offset) comes from.

Comment: And V_Offset is OFFSET_V in the schematic. It’s a buffered version of 5V/2 (2.5V) from R21 and R22. It’s also the midpoint value that makes the most sense for the Arduino’s input range.

Comment: You say "Now the capacitors are probably all 0.1uF. C5 and C9 may be less than that. But depending on the required bandwidth, 0.1uF is OK.” What is your principle for selecting capacitor values?

Comment: Select a bandwidth that will  provide an anti-alias filter that has a cutoff below 1/2 the sample rate.

Comment: thank you so much.