# Short circuit in ribbon cable

Tags: short-circuit, ribbon-cable

My ribbon cable assemblies are creating intermittent short circuits that cause my Atmega328p microprocessor to spontaneously reset.

The setup: 60-conductor .05 ribbon cable made by 3M (long ago when prices were more reasonable than today), separated to use 34 of the conductors and trimmed to length with sharp scissors. 34-position IDC connectors made by Marvic International designed to terminate .05 ribbon cable. Connectors crimped onto ends of cables using a Hilitand-style crimping tool (including the yellow boat that holds the connector). Cable folded over connector and strain relief applied. Inserted into 34-position PCB header made by On Shore Technology, hand soldered onto PCB made by ExpressPCB. I can't think of anything else that might be relevant to the problem.

The problem occurs when I move the cable even slightly. It occurs even when only one end of the cable is connected to a header and even when only that end is terminated. The problem does NOT occur when I remove the cable from the header and wiggle the header or flex the board. I've done what I can to make sure that the conductors at the ends of the cable aren't shorting (cautery with a lighter, scraping with a razor blade, making the cable end flush with the IDC connector). I've made and remade the cable assembly several times. I can't see any glitches in the power supply to the board that are visible on my oscilloscope, but I think the microprocessor must be detecting a brown-out condition because I don't know why else it would be resetting.

1. Photo attached [image: IDC connector]
2. I haven't measured a short circuit. I've inferred that it must be the problem because merely flexing the cable provokes the problem. I don't have a way to measure capacitance, but the signals being put on the lines are in the kilohertz range. As I said, I closed the IDC connector with a standard tool, and (which I didn't mention) verified continuity of all the conductors.
3. A floating reset pin was an inspired guess. I have it hard-wired to pin 10 on an Arduino Uno to facilitate burning hardware. It also has a 10K pull-up resistor attached, though. So probably not this cause. The problem occurs with cables about 15 inches and 36 inches long. I don't know what to do to check for EM interference.
4. The problem occurs even when the other end of the cable isn't attached to anything. The signals on the lines are square waves in the low kilohertz range.
5. I used rosin-core solder without separate flux to solder components to the board.
6. I don't know the cause of the reset. The fuses are programmed so that the brown-out voltage is around 2 V; the supply voltage is 5 V with a commercial (NAEMATEK?) power supply and the watchdog timer is disabled. I think I can rule out the timer in any case because sometimes the resets occur in very rapid succession. One of the timers is in use by the Arduino OS for controlling the serial port; I don't know if another timer might be running without my knowledge.

FURTHER UPDATE: Instead of a ribbon cable, I attached 34 jumpers to the header. Lo, and behold, I can provoke the resets by wiggling those jumpers. That suggests that my problem lies in the way the header is connected to the board. Instead of tying some of the header pins to interior layers for power and ground, perhaps I should have used surface traces?[image: jumpers replacing ribbon cable]

EVEN FURTHER UPDATE: I slowed the signals down to 1 Hz, hoping to eliminate any RF interference. No joy.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the IDC part of the connector?

Comment: Have you actually measured a short circuit with a meter? Have you ruled out inter-cable capacitance? Data sheet links are likely required. What tool did you use for closing the IDC connector?

Comment: If you have a floating reset pin and some sharply falling waveform right next to it, it can bring reset active. Any device nearby can also conduct or radiate electromagnetic interference. Even missing bypass caps cause problems. How long is the cable?

Comment: You don't say what the ribbon cable is joining ... what are the signals on it?

Comment: I've seen where "no-clean" flux could be [conductive](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159492/chipquick-smd291-no-clean-paste-flux-conductive), rendering rework necessary.  There are a lot of variables to this problem - photos and oscilloscope captures could help.

Comment: What's the reset cause? Power-on, low voltage detect, watchdog, clock failure?

Comment: Try to narrow down the set of wires causing the problem. Magic aside, the problem could be in electrical interference (low probability as there're no high currents), something shorts (means bad soldering - use microscope to examine - from solder side and from connector side - ideally moving plastic up to see the solder joints), or just a defect in the PCB (to identify for it only x-ray will help). If you have the project and PCB design analyze it to see where is the highest probability of tracks being shorted near the connector joints.

Comment: Check clearances, especially between power polygons/tracks and signals/pins.

Comment: What if you touch the reset wire? Does the MCU reset at maybe 50 or 60 times per second?

Comment: Justme: If I ground the reset pin, it resets exactly once.

Comment: @WalterOney - Hi, While we do encourage OPs to update their question, as they discover more details, you seem to be adding details but leaving now-disproved details, which can mislead readers e.g. the title is "Short circuit in ribbon cable" but you've removed the ribbon cable & the resets still happen. I recommend you go through and update *all* info to the latest state of knowledge. (There is an edit history, but I would also add a section at the bottom saying that short circuits in the cable were an initial suspect, but this was disproved by your test replacing cable with jumper wires).

Comment: @WalterOney - Are you able to add the schematic for the board(s)? Are you able to answer the earlier comment from *Lundin* regarding investigating the reset reason logged by the MCU (obviously you'll need to write code to do that and output the result)? Given that you can provoke the problem with those jumper wires attached, have you tried to minimise the test case i.e. remove all possible wires but still trigger the problem? Which wires (connected to which signals) are absolutely required for you to trigger the problem? Then IMHO we'd need the schematic & close-up photos of the board.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove the top portion of the ribbon connector and examine how the pins have pierced the ribbon cable.  I sometimes find a similar problem when the ribbon cable was installed crooked and the pins are not exactly centered on the conductors.

If this has indeed happened, you can carefully peel the ribbon from the pins (starting at one end), cut the affected portion of the cable off, then reinstalling the connector.

I find that one can reuse the ribbon connectors several times (2 or 3), at least for quality connectors.

Comment: Mr. Reid: That was another inspired suggestion, but it didn't yield fruit (all the conductors were pierced as they should be, and no two adjacent wires were shorted). BUT I tried cutting the cable off as a prelude to taking off the locking strip. I couldn't reproduce my problem even with fairly severe jiggling of the cable. That leaves inter-wire capacitance or a cable defect as the culprit. I'll see if I can find a low-capacitance ribbon cable at an affordable price.